# Matching % logic between two user profiles

Tags: matching

I would like to get algorithm or formula or equation to find matching `%` between two users based on attended questions. Please find below as an example for one case.

```
Total: 200 Q
User A: 100 Q
User B: 120 Q
Common : 90 Q
Common Correct: 60 Q
Matching % of A & B = ?
```

Mind that if both users have only 1 common question and it is matched then it still should not be `100%` match It is very similar to okcupid site but only difference is that i don't have importance of question and also not expected answer option in question

Can anyone please help me to prepare formula to find matching `%?`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If answers are not important, then it seems that

```
Matching = Common / UserA * Common / UserB
```

Matching changes from 0 (no common questions) to 1 (`User A` and `User B` answered the same set of questions).

Comment: Can you elaborate final % for above example? Are you considering both common questions and matched answers out of common questions?

Comment: @Nikul Matching is 67,5% (90 / 100 * 90 / 120) in the example above. Only common questions are considered, because there is no information about common answers and how different answers for the same question are matching.

Comment: All answers have boolean values so we can match one to one. Also in your formula in case of (90 / 90 * 90 / 90) will become 100% because 100% should only be case when (200 / 200 * 200 / 200).... so i think need to use all figures like common questions, common answers, all questions, questions of userA and questions of userB... hope you understand!!!

Comment: Can anyone help me on this ?